# applying a function to all columns to extract ranks of each column value from a larger file and calculate rank sum

Tags: python, merge, pandas, extract

I am trying to iterate or create a function that loops over columns in a pandas data frame. This function is supposed to take the values in each column and search a larger file for these values. Then I want it to extract the ranks of these target values and obtain a vector with the rank sum of values obtained from all 100 columns.

The 100 column file is called simulation.txt that looks like this:

```
SIM0    SIM1    SIM2    ...SIM100
rs168   rs668   rs228   ...rs930
rs466   rs751   rs109   ...rs216
rs484   rs139   rs636   ...rs755
rs104   rs226   rs1540  ...rs671
rs123   rs377   rs732   ...rs672
```

The larger file I need to search is rs_ranks.txt, it looks like this:

```
rsid    Rank
rs168   1
rs464   2
rs485   3
rs110   4
rs129   5
rs297   6
rs139   7
.       .
.       .
.       .
.       .
.       .
rs105   2498509
```

I want to extract SIM0 from simulation.txt,then I want to obtain the rank of the rs numbers from SIM0 in rs_ranks.txt. After I get the ranks of the rs numbers in the SIM0 column, I'd like to calculate the rank sum.

EXAMPLE: If I were to extract the ranks of SIM0 from rs_ranks, I'd get something like this:

```
    SIM0    Rank
    rs168   1
    rs466   49
    rs484   398208
    rs104   402487
    rs123   2972
```

The rank sum of SIM0 would be=803717
    rank_sum_vector(803717,SIM1_ranksum,SIM2_ranksum,SIM100_ranksum)

Finally, I would like to be able to do this for all 100 columns of simulation text so in the end I have a ranksum vector of 100 rank sum values corresponding to all 100 columns.

Please help! I don't know how to create a function that will iter over each column and do this. I have been thinking about using the merge function but I'm not sure how to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: Question: in one SIMx there is only one rsid or there can be multiple instances of the same one?

Comment: the rsids in SIMs are randomly sampled so for example, rs1 can appear in SIM1,SIM40, SIM99 columns etc.

Comment: Ok, but in SIM1 there can be only one instance of rs1, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) using the [Series `get` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.get.html):

```
In [11]: res = df.applymap(rs.get)

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
   SIM0  SIM1  SIM2
0   388   386   491
1   148   471   171
2   162   261   276
3   910   780   445
4   952   673   367
```

and then [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
In [13]: df.sum()
Out[13]:
SIM0    2560
SIM1    2571
SIM2    1750
dtype: int64
```

*(I've used a random series `rs` of integers, rather than the partial you gave)*

To get the DataFrame and Series, you could use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) as follows:

```
In [31]: df = pd.read_csv('simulation.txt')

In [32]: rs = pd.read_csv('rs_ranks.txt').set_index('rsid')['Rank']

In [33]: rs
Out[33]:
rsid
rs168    1
rs464    2
rs485    3
rs110    4
rs129    5
rs297    6
rs139    7
Name: Rank, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks, but can you please elaborate a but more how you did this? what is rs.get doing?

Comment: rs is a Series, it's calling the get method (just like `rs['rs168']` gets 1 in your Series)